# Combining Multimaps with respect to Functional Dependencies

Tags: java, algorithm, multimap

Given a multimap, I need to combine the entries with respect to their functional dependencies.

I might have misused the term *functional dependency*. What I mean is:

If I have three entries of multimap:

```
a -> b c d

b -> c e f

g -> f h i
```

I want to combine them as

```
a -> c e d f

g -> h i
```

`e` and `f` go to `a` because `b` is a value of `a` and `c, e, f` are values of `b`.

`h` and `i` go to `g` because neither `g` nor `h` are values of `a`.

`f` does not go to `a` because it appears in values of `a` (priority is ascending).

Here is the code I've written, which gives `ConcurrentModificationError`:

```
Multimap<Integer, Integer> map = TreeMultimap.create();
Multimap<Integer, Integer> map2 = TreeMultimap.create();
map.put(0, 1);
map.put(0, 3);
map.put(0, 4);
map.put(1, 3);
map.put(1, 4);
map.put(1, 6);
map.put(3, 7);
map.put(3, 9);
map.put(3, 10);
map.put(2, 7);
map.put(2, 8);
map.put(2, 9);
System.out.println(map);
    for(int i : map.keySet())
    {
        for(int j : map.get(i))
        {
            if(map.containsKey(j))
            {
                Collection<Integer> list = map.get(j);
                map2.putAll(i, map.get(j));
                map.values().removeAll(list);
            }
        }
        if(!map.values().contains(i))
            map2.putAll(i, map.get(i));
    }
System.out.println(map2);
```

The output is:

```
{0=[1, 3, 4], 1=[3, 4, 6], 2=[7, 8, 9], 3=[7, 9, 10]}
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedCollection$WrappedIterator.next(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:486)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:68)
```

However, I expect it to be:

```
{0=[1, 3, 4], 1=[3, 4, 6], 2=[7, 8, 9], 3=[7, 9, 10]}
{0=[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10], 2=[8]}
```

### P.S.

A key is always mapped to three values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over map, and modify it at the same time. The easiest thing you can do to fix your code, is to create a new map as you go through the input rather than modifying the existing one in place.

Comment: you are removing values from the original map now. Don't :)You can't iterate through the map and modify it at the same time.

Also, I don't understand what you are trying to do with this `map.values().contains(i)`. The values in the map are lists, there can't be an integer ... Perhaps, you mean `if(map.contains(i))`, but that is always true, because `i` is the key in the `map`.

Comment: @Dima I don't get any syntax errors. Perhaps you confuse `Multimap` with `Map`.

Comment: Ah, never mind, indeed `map.values` returns a Collection<V>.
I still don't get why you need that piece. 
More importantly, do not modify the original map. That's what causes your exception.

Comment: I know what not to do, I ask what to do.

Comment: Remove this line `map.values().removeAll(list);`

Comment: It does not solve my problem. I want to remove all the values that are present in `map.get(j)`.

Comment: Well, this wasn't a part of the original question. Are you talking about a different problem now?
The bottom line is you cannot modify the map while iterating over it. If you need the original map modified, you need to think of a different algorithm of doing it.

Comment: I don't think you get the original problem. Please read the post carefully. The desired output contains no duplicate values.

Comment: Would you like me to write the correct algorithm for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct way to do it. I don't know if the algorithm can get any more efficient, but this is all I have right now:

```
Multimap<Integer, Integer> map = TreeMultimap.create();
Multimap<Integer, Integer> map2 = TreeMultimap.create();
map.put(0, 1);
map.put(0, 3);
map.put(0, 4);
map.put(1, 3);
map.put(1, 4);
map.put(1, 6);
map.put(3, 7);
map.put(3, 9);
map.put(3, 10);
map.put(2, 7);
map.put(2, 8);
map.put(2, 9);
System.out.println(map);
for(int i : map.keySet())
{
    for(int j : map.get(i))
        if(map.containsKey(j))
            map2.putAll(i, map.get(j));
    if(!map.values().contains(i))
        map2.putAll(i, map.get(i));
}
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i : map2.keySet())
    result.add(new ArrayList<>(map2.get(i)));


Collections.reverse(result);
for(int i=0; i<result.size()-1; i++)
{
    Iterator<Integer> it = result.get(i).iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        int j = it.next();
        if(result.get(i+1).contains(j))
            it.remove();
    }
}
result.removeAll(Collections.singleton(Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
map.clear();
Collections.reverse(result);
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++)
    map.putAll(i, result.get(i));
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{0=[1, 3, 4], 1=[3, 4, 6], 2=[7, 8, 9], 3=[7, 9, 10]}
{0=[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10], 1=[8]}
```